# How to achieve pagination on duplicate data in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have collection name recommends and where users recommend papers question and feeds.According to my requirement if I follow 10 person,then i should get all their recommended data with pagination.I am using latest mongodb version

```
recommended:[{
        "_id": "5bbc7c87a1d19614c093145c",
        "userId": "1",
        "recommended": "quest1",
        "recommendType": "questions",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:43.093Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:43.093Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7c78a1d19614c093143a",
        "userId": "2",
        "recommended": "quest1",
        "recommendType": "questions",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:28.255Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:28.255Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7c6fa1d19614c0931426",
        "userId": "3",
        "recommended": "quest2",
        "recommendType": "questions",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:19.428Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T10:01:19.428Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7b64a1d19614c09311e7",
        "userId": "4",
        "recommended": "quest3",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:56:52.193Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:56:52.193Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7a17bd1f151bccea1b24",
        "userId": "1",
        "recommended": "paper1",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:19.637Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:19.637Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7a0ebd1f151bccea1b1e",
        "userId": "2",
        "recommended": "paper2",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:10.656Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:10.656Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7a05bd1f151bccea1b16",
        "userId": "3",
        "recommended": "paper3",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:01.615Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:51:01.615Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc79f7bd1f151bccea1b0e",
        "userId": "4",
        "recommended": "paper1",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:47.956Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:47.956Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc79eebd1f151bccea1b08",
        "userId": "5",
        "recommended": "quest1",
        "recommendType": "questions",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:38.658Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:38.658Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc79e2bd1f151bccea1b00",
        "userId": "6",
        "recommended": "paper2",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:26.624Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:50:26.624Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc795bbd1f151bccea0a4f",
        "userId": "1",
        "recommended": "paper7",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:48:11.660Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:48:11.660Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc78f9bd1f151bcce9e9d7",
        "userId": "6",
        "recommended": "quest6",
        "recommendType": "paperupload",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:46:33.914Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:46:33.914Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7865a93f7f0e54f63b97",
        "userId": "1",
        "recommended": "feed1",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:44:05.961Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:44:05.961Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc785ca93f7f0e54f63b80",
        "userId": "2",
        "recommended": "feed2",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:56.450Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:56.450Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7854a93f7f0e54f63b70",
        "userId": "3",
        "recommended": "feed3",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:48.634Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:48.634Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc784da93f7f0e54f63b61",
        "userId": "4",
        "recommended": "feed8",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:41.458Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:41.458Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7845a93f7f0e54f63b4c",
        "userId": "6",
        "recommended": "feed5",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:33.330Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:43:33.330Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc7800a93f7f0e54f63ab0",
        "userId": "6",
        "recommended": "paper1",
        "recommendType": "papers",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:24.658Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:24.658Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc77f8a93f7f0e54f63a9f",
        "userId": "8",
        "recommended": "quest1",
        "recommendType": "questions",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:16.182Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:16.182Z",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5bbc77eea93f7f0e54f63a8e",
        "userId": "5",
        "recommended": "feed1",
        "recommendType": "feeds",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:06.798Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-09T09:42:06.798Z"
    }];
```

I follow 7 people

```
var followedId=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
```

I query for my followers recommended data  using find query with pagination from 0-5 so i will get results with repeated documents with same quest or paper or feeds.so how do  i make my every pagination result unique and also same paper or question should not appear twice after each pagination(that is my result set should always have latest recommended with no duplicates after each pagination)

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this  by  mongodb  queries

Comment: Where would the `'7'` in your result come from? What is the definition of "following"? Also, kindly get rid of the clutter - `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are certainly unrelated to the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
Recommend.aggregate([
        {$match: {$and: [{userId: {$in: FollowedUsers}}]}},
        // { "$match": { "userId":{ "$in": FollowedUsers }}},
        { $sort: {"createdAt": -1 } },
        { $group: {
            _id: "$recommended",
            count:{$sum:1},
            recommendType: { "$first": "$recommendType" },
            rec_id:{"$first": "$_id"},
            createdAt:{"$first": "$createdAt"}

        }},
        { $sort: {count: -1 } },
        {$skip: page*pageSize},
        {$limit: pageSize}
        ])
```

Comment: This will fetch the recommended table Ids query with $in in recommended table, by using find query and populate everything